# python: getting the perimeter points from inputted points

Tags: python, list

Good day guys! I'm new at programming and i'm studying python
I have a problem here:
as you can see i am creating a program which lets you input coordinates of points and then identify which points will be the outermost of all points(perimeter of all points). The program will produce an output of list of points in the perimeter and another list of points inside the perimeter. Im using centroid of all points as basis of distances of all points but i cant find the way how i should identify each point that will create a perimeter out of all points

```
import math
b=[]
a=[]
x1=[]
y1=[]
d1=[]

def cent(x):
  return(sum(x)/len(x))
def dist (a,b,c,d):
  return (math.sqrt(((c-a)**2)+((d-b)**2)))

c=2
print('Enter Point Coordinates')
while c>1:
  x=int(input('x='))
  y=int(input('y='))
  b.append(x)
  b.append(y)
  x1.append(x)
  y1.append(y)
  a.append(b)
  b=[]
  r=input('Add more points?(Y/N): ')
  if r.upper() == 'Y':
    c+=1
  else:
    c=0

#print(cent(x1))
n=len(x1)
xc=cent(x1)
yc=cent(y1)

for i in range (n):
  d=dist(xc,yc,x1[i],y1[i])
  d1.append(d)

print (d1)
```

im stuck here... i putted all of my distances from the centroid into a list

```
#print(xc)
#print(yc)
#print(a)    
#print(x1)
#print(y1)
```

Comment: you are looking for the so-called "convex hull" of the points. This is not a trivial problem (if you want an efficient solution), but there are libraries capable of doing this.

Comment: ive been looking for the right term so its convex hull? do you know any libraries for this?

Comment: SciPy and shapely could be two possible libraries. But just google for *convex hull algorithm* to know more, of *convex hull python* to find libraries

Comment: thanks the convex hull is the key word. i saw some algorithm and codes its a bit advance for me im still learning list/arrays but i think i can learn it thanks a lot guys!